# Signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) in app without native code and I am unable to narrow down the cause of the problem

Tags: crash, native

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000229f44  /system/lib64/libskia.so (SkCanvas::onDrawTextBlob(SkTextBlob const*, float, float, SkPaint const&)+536)
  #01  pc 000000000022a900  /system/lib64/libskia.so (SkCanvas::drawTextBlob(SkTextBlob const*, float, float, SkPaint const&)+236)
  #02  pc 0000000000292d04  /system/lib64/libskia.so (SkColorSpaceXformCanvas::onDrawTextBlob(SkTextBlob const*, float, float, SkPaint const&)+84)
  #03  pc 000000000022a900  /system/lib64/libskia.so (SkCanvas::drawTextBlob(SkTextBlob const*, float, float, SkPaint const&)+236)
  #04  pc 00000000000c53c4  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::SkiaCanvas::drawGlyphs(std::__1::function, int, SkPaint const&, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)+288)
  #05  pc 000000000005386c  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::DrawTextFunctor::operator()(unsigned long, unsigned long)+168)
  #06  pc 0000000000053320  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (void android::MinikinUtils::forFontRun(minikin::Layout const&, android::Paint*, android::DrawTextFunctor&)+532)
  #07  pc 0000000000053034  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::Canvas::drawText(unsigned short const*, int, int, int, float, float, int, android::Paint const&, android::Typeface*)+276)
  #08  pc 0000000000133f1c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::CanvasJNI::drawTextRunString(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, long, _jstring*, int, int, int, int, float, float, unsigned char, long, long)+156)
  #09  pc 0000000000b80a14  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawTextRun [DEDUPED]+260)
  #10  pc 0000000000b845b0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawTextRun+944)
  #11  pc 0000000000b94e58  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.graphics.Canvas.drawTextRun+56)
  #12  pc 00000000012c66cc  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.TextLine.drawTextRun+124)
  #13  pc 00000000012c842c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.TextLine.handleText+1340)
  #14  pc 00000000012c7bd4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.TextLine.handleRun+2756)
  #15  pc 00000000012c6450  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.TextLine.drawRun+352)
  #16  pc 00000000012c8bb4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.TextLine.draw+148)
  #17  pc 0000000001296030  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.Layout.drawText+3216)
  #18  pc 0000000001294be8  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.text.Layout.draw+184)
  #19  pc 000000000152b9ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.widget.TextView.onDraw+3276)
  #20  pc 000000000054b388  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #21  pc 00000000000dd574  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #22  pc 000000000029adb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
  #23  pc 00000000002953a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696)
  #24  pc 0000000000533b44  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+1384)
  #25  pc 000000000053d094  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14356)
  #26  pc 0000000000275804  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
  #27  pc 000000000027b40c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+216)
  #28  pc 0000000000295380  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+664)
  #29  pc 0000000000536224  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+812)
  #30  pc 0000000000540d94  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #31  pc 0000000000275804  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
  #32  pc 00000000005260d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1052)
  #33  pc 000000000055450c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #34  pc 00000000010ae41c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x659000) (android.view.View.draw+252)
  #35  pc 000000000054b388  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #36  pc 00000000000dd574  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #37  pc 000000000029adb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+344)
  #38  pc 00000000002953a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696)
  #39  pc 0000000000533b44  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeSuper+1384)
  #40  pc 000000000053d094  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14356)
  #41  pc 0000000000275804  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+444)
  #42  pc 00000000005260d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1052)
  #43  pc 000000000055450c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #44  pc 0000000000035c48  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)